# How replace text into HTML hyperlink?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to replace all occurrences of WordPress post text with an HTML hyperlink. I am using the below code. It works fine when the text is plain text, but if the text is a link e.g https://example.com/test/test1/ it does not work. There are links and text in my post that I want to make clickable. Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or suggest to me another method that is efficient?

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content','SoniReplace',10);
    
function SoniReplace($content){
    
    foreach($response as $value){
       $name_value=explode(",",$value);
       $name=$name_value[0];
       $value=$name_value[1];
       $link='<a href='.$value.'>'.$name.'</a>';

       $content=str_replace($name,$link,$content);
     }
    
     return $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you echo out $link?  I suspect the issue may have something to do with the value of the href not being encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: maybe try $link='<a href="'.$value."'>'.$name.'</a>';

Comment: $link is okay. I have print it on screen.

Comment: It seems it does not replace the link correctly.